# iframe containing external wesbite does not fire the onscroll event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, scroll

I understand that in order to fire the onscroll event handler in an iframe normally, the iframe must contain a site with the same domain name as the page that contains the iframe. But is there anyway at all that this can be done for an iframe that contains an external site?

The onscroll event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
       var frm = document.getElementById("test").contentWindow;
       frm.onscroll = function(){
          alert("iframe scrolled");
       }
    }
</script>
```

The above js code works just fine for this:

```
<iframe id="test" src="http://www.<myDomain>.com"></iframe>
```

but not for this:

```
<iframe id="test" src="http://www.<anExternalSite>.com"></iframe>
```

If I can't do this my entire application will be useless. is there any workaround for doing this? any hack?

Comment: I hope not, the xss is quite powerful as it is already :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arbitrary external sites? No.

Co-operative external sites? Have the scroll event listener be bound by the site itself (to its body element) and communicate the event data using [postMessage](http://caniuse.com/x-doc-messaging).

Comment: That's probably the way to go about this. But not in my case as I can't cooperate with the external websites. I have asked another question with regards to this matter.[Rails: Serve an external webpage as my own domain - URL to be used in iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415936/rails-serve-an-external-webpage-as-my-own-domain-url-to-be-used-in-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Quentin's answer or do something more hacky, serve the external site from your own domain using a proxy (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), because the crossdomain policy won't let you do this.

Be aware that the proxy will increase the traffic on your server.

Comment: is this what stumbleupon.com does?

Comment: sorry, I'm new to stumbleupon.com, where can I see this?

Comment: [link](gttp://stumbleupon.com). This is an example of a stumbleupon URL: http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/8eOp42/www.calm.com/

Comment: Nope, they are loading that site from an external domain, but, I don't see anything happening on scroll... Would you like to adapt the iframe's height as they do? there is no need of listening to the iframe's inner scroll event for that.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Looking at the url of the stumbled pages I was hoping stumbleupon serves the external sites as its own as well. But took a look at the code and figured they simply use an iframe with the external site url as the source. Is there an example of using a proxy to this that you can point me to? Do you think that's still the right way to go for an app with many (probably millions of) concurrent users?

Comment: The **Cross-document messaging** looks nice (or even the **swf localconnection**) but you'll have to insert some js in the external site, and you won't have access to the external site right?. Maybe if you specify your requirements (on another question) we could suggest another solution avoiding the iframe interaction.

Comment: Thanks for your help coma. I have asked another question: [Rails: Serve an external webpage as my own domain - URL to be used in iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415936/rails-alternative-to-iframes-containing-external-websites)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        #iframeoverlay { position: absolute; width: same-as-iframe; height: sams-as-iframe; anything-else: sams-as-iframe; z-index: 1-or-higher-if-the-iframe-is-over-1; }
      </style>
      <script>
        function alert() {
          alert("iframe scrolled");
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <iframe ... ></iframe><div id="iframeoverlay" onscroll="alert"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Not sure if it'll work but try it.

Comment: the #iframeoverlay being on top of the iframe won't let the iframe scroll. I also can't set the scrollTop value of an iframe containing an external site.